# Issue with a string concatenation adding an undesirable character

Tags: javascript, regex, while-loop

I developed this algorithm below. The objective is to return the first letter in the case it is a vowel. Exemple: 'egg' -> It should return: 'e' and when I have a single consonant it should return, like this example: 'car' -> it should return 'c'. When I have a cluster of consonants like 'glove' it must return 'gl'. Only in the case of the single vowel, it is returning successfully as expected. In the case of single consonant or cluster of consonant, it is returning with a undesireble vowel added like these examples below:

```
solution('egg') // -> It is returning 'e' as expected. OK RIGHT! 
solution('car') // -> It is returning 'ca'. It is expected: 'c'. WRONG!
solution('glove') // -> It is returning 'glo'. It is expected: 'gl'. WRONG!
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
 function solution(str) {
  
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi
  let currentIndex = 0
  let currentCharacter = str[currentIndex ] 
  let consonants = ''
  let outputStr = ''

  if (vowels.test(currentCharacter)) {
    outputStr = currentCharacter   

  } else {
    while (true) {
      if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) {     
        currentCharacter = str[currentIndex]
        consonants += currentCharacter    
        currentIndex ++ 
      } else {
        break
      }
    }

    outputStr = `${consonants}`   
  }

  return outputStr
}

console.log(solution('glove'))
```

Comment: just as an idea `function solution(str) { return str.match(/[^aeiou]+|.?/i)[0] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current attempt is the following snippet:

```
while (true) {
  if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) {     
    currentCharacter = str[currentIndex]
    consonants += currentCharacter    
    currentIndex ++ 
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

There are two things going wrong here.

1. You test `vowels` against `currentCharacter`. If `currentCharacter` is not a vowel you should add it to the output directly. You currently first change the value of `currentCharacter` before adding it to the output.
2. You currently set a new value of `currentCharacter` before incrementing `currentIndex`. This should be done after.

Let me unroll the loop and demonstrate the issue:

```
/* str = "car"
 * vowels = /[aeiou]/gi
 * currentIndex = 0
 * currentCharacter = "c"
 * consonants = ""
 */

if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) //=> true

currentCharacter = str[currentIndex];
/* currentIndex = 0
 * currentCharacter = "c"
 * consonants = ""
 */

consonants += currentCharacter
/* currentIndex = 0
 * currentCharacter = "c"
 * consonants = "c"
 */

currentIndex ++
/* currentIndex = 1
 * currentCharacter = "c"
 * consonants = "c"
 */

if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) //=> true

currentCharacter = str[currentIndex];
/* currentIndex = 1
 * currentCharacter = "a"
 * consonants = "c"
 */

consonants += currentCharacter
/* currentIndex = 1
 * currentCharacter = "a"
 * consonants = "ca"
 */

currentIndex ++
/* currentIndex = 2
 * currentCharacter = "a"
 * consonants = "ca"
 */

if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) //=> false
```

To solve this issue you only have to move the assignment of the `currentCharacter` and place it after the increment of `currentIndex`.

```
while (true) {
  if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) {     
    consonants += currentCharacter
    currentIndex ++ 
    currentCharacter = str[currentIndex] // <- moved two lines down
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

```js
 function solution(str) {
  
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi
  let currentIndex = 0
  let currentCharacter = str[currentIndex ] 
  let consonants = ''
  let outputStr = ''

  if (vowels.test(currentCharacter)) {
    outputStr = currentCharacter   

  } else {
    while (true) {
      if (!vowels.test(currentCharacter)) {     
        consonants += currentCharacter    
        currentIndex ++ 
        currentCharacter = str[currentIndex]
      } else {
        break
      }
    }

    outputStr = `${consonants}`   
  }

  return outputStr
}

console.log(solution('glove'))
```

Comment: I did your request and it continues not working. In the case of this entry 'glove' the output should be 'gl' NOT 'g'

Comment: @claudiobitar Did you run the snippet? The output is `"gl"`.

Comment: Ohh sorry! Thank you! When I had tested maybe I forgot to save or I did some foolly mistake. Now I have been tested again and it is working successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an alternation starting with an anchor `^` to match either a vowel `[aeiou]` asserting a consonant at the right, or the other way around matching 1 or more consonants.

```
\b(?:[aeiou](?=[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])|[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+(?=[aeiou]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sel7HV/1)

```js
function solution(str) {
  const regex = /^(?:[aeiou](?=[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])|[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+(?=[aeiou]))/i;
  let m = str.match(regex);
  return m ? m[0] : str;
}

console.log(solution('egg'));
console.log(solution('car'));
console.log(solution('glove'));
```